# EC2 User Data copying outdated version of a file in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So, I'm trying to setup a Jenkins server in a EC2 instance and use CasC with it. I created an S3 bucket to store the CasC configuration and setup a user data script to copy that configuration into the specific path.
Everything goes well in the first run of the user data script and the file gets copied to the correct path. However, when I upload a new version of the file and reboot the EC2 instance, it seems that the aws cli is copying the old version, no matter how many times I reboot the instance after that.
Here's my user data script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo su -
yum update -y
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl stop jenkins

aws s3 cp s3://jenkins-casc/jenkins.yaml /var/lib/jenkins/

systemctl start jenkins
```

And here's the cloud-init output for the copy command:

```
download: s3://jenkins-casc/jenkins.yaml to var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.yaml
```

Comment: User data gets only executed once on **first** boot by default, are you executing the script again manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Data scripts are only executed on the "first boot" of the instance. (Actually, it is "first boot for a given Instance ID".)

If you want a script to execute on *every* boot, put it in this directory:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

This is a feature of [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).